# Wordpress изменил доменое имя и сервер стало не коректно работать coustumiz

Tags: wordpress

у меня есть такое проблема
изменил доменое имя и сервер, сайт стало не коректно работать, в базу данных изменил все урл линки которые связаны со старим сайтом
сейчас когда откриваю раздель Customize Your Site [image: reverce]

становится таким а дольжно быт такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сайт надо переносить [правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас некорректно перенесена база данных, поэтому не все скрипты и стили подгружаются верно. Подставьте в запросы ниже свои значения нового и старого домена, выполните запрос в базу.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'http://old-site.com', 'https://new-site.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://old-site.com', 'https://new-site.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://old-site.com','https://new-site.com');
```

Comment: Это ответ НЕЛЬЗЯ делать. Как делать правильно и почему - по ссылке в комментариях в вопросу.

Comment: Посмотри вопрос, у человека стили полетели, стили подключаются по абсолютному пути \\\

Comment: Посмотри по умной ссылке и учись. "стили полетели"...